# Can I refresh the Registry Editor console?

Tags: windows-registry

I'm doing some script-based changes that involve registry edits. Once the script runs, I want to verify in the regedit console that the values have been added. However, upon checking regedit, only new values show up after closing and expanding the key, not new keys and their values. In order to get the new keys to appear, I have to close and reopen regedit.

Is there a button to refresh your view within regedit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, <kbd>F5</kbd> causes refresh, as does that key in many other applications. See [DefKey.com](https://defkey.com/windows-registry-editor-shortcuts) for some other keyboard shortcuts.

BTW, a shortcut *not* mentioned there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to clear the contents of the location bar. The key combo must be pressed *twice* to work though. This odd behavior was noticed when I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select all, which it does *not* do.

Comment: Boy do I feel silly not trying F5...